How to merge two different pbix files having different dataset in single file in power bi desktop
is it possible to merge two different pbix files in single pbix file like
customer.pbix and sales.pbix file can be merged and create single file in power bi desktop

You cannot merge the two separate .pbix files but you can create two thin reports which share the same semantic model. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/report-separate-from-model

Thanks for answering,
In tableau we can import different dashboards from different file is it possible in power bi desktop. or we can create different datasets in power bi from different sources like SQLserver, Excel file and Oracle etc

Yes, you can import different datasets into Power BI.
