PowerBI Desktop PBIX file merging
Is there any way we can merge two separate .PBIX files into single file?
(without manually copy pasting dataset and each report page)
We can share the dataset by using PowerBI service, Yes.
But I am looking for a solution without licensing.

No it's a manual copy and paste process

Possible duplicate of this SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78376363/how-to-merge-two-different-pbix-files-having-different-dataset-in-single-file-in?rq=2
